# Pandas set value if all columns are equal in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Dataframe that I read in this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, delimiter=";")
df = df.set_index('date')
print(df)


      NET_0  NET_1  NET_2  NET_3  NET_4  NET_5  NET_6  NET_7  NET_8  NET_9  NET_10  NET_11  NET_12  NET_13  NET_14  NET_15  NET_16  NET_17  NET_18  NET_19  NET_20  NET_21  NET_22  NET_23  NET_24  NET_25
date                                                                                                                                                                                                            
2009-08-02      0      0      0      1      1      1      0      1      1      0       0       1       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       1       1       1       1
2009-08-03      0      0      0      1      1      1      0      0      1      0       1       1       0       0       1       1       0       0       0       0       1       0       1       1       1       1
2009-08-04      0      0      0      1      1      1      0      1      1      0       0       1       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       1       1       1       1
2009-08-05      0      0      0      1      1      1      0      1      1      0       1       1       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       1       1       1       1
2009-08-06      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      
2009-08-07      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

I want this results: if all net_* columns in a row are equals to one I want `1` as results, if all columns in a row are equals to 0 `-1` else `0`.  Something like:

```
date    enseamble
2009-08-02     0
2009-08-03     0
2009-08-04     0
2009-08-05     0
2009-08-06     -1
2009-08-07     1
```

There is a fast way without for? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`np.select()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=np+select&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=np+select&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j35i39j0l2.2486j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
m1=df.eq(1).all(axis=1) #check if all column in each row is 1
m2=df.eq(0).all(axis=1) ##check if all column in each row is 0
```

---

*using `np.select()` to then pass the condition list and the choice list against each condition(refer docs in the link provided)*

```
df['enseamble']=np.select([m1,m2],[1,-1],0) #using np.select expaination in docs
#to drop the remaining columns f, find difference between enseamble and other columns like below and call under axis=1:
m=df.drop(df.columns.difference(['enseamble']),axis=1) 
print(m)

                     enseamble
date                         0
2009-08-02 00:00:00          0
2009-08-03 00:00:00          0
2009-08-04 00:00:00          0
2009-08-05 00:00:00          0
2009-08-06 00:00:00         -1
2009-08-07 00:00:00          1
```

Comment: Great answer. Can you write some comments to explain how the code works? I'll mark as correct answer

Comment: @AsoStrife done..!! let me know if you need anything for understanding..:)

Comment: I've ask something very similar today here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421118/pandas-set-value-if-most-columns-are-equal-in-a-dataframe 
can you check please?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), I think the `all()` function will work for you. (Especially because your data seems to be in boolean form.)

```
df.all(axis=None)
```

This will evaluate the whole dataframe and return a True or False.