# Pandas set value if most columns are equal in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

starting by another my question I've done yesterday [Pandas set value if all columns are equal in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403075/pandas-set-value-if-all-columns-are-equal-in-a-dataframe)

Starting by @anky_91 solution I'm working on something similar.
Instead of put `1` or `-1` if all columns are equals I want something more flexible. 
In fact I want `1` if (for example) the 70% percentage of the columns are `1`, `-1` for the same but inverse condition and `0` else.

So this is what I've wrote:

```
# Instead of using .all I use .sum to count the occurence of 1 and 0 for each row
m1 = local_df.eq(1).sum(axis=1)
m2 = local_df.eq(0).sum(axis=1)

# Debug print, it work
print(m1)
print(m2)
```

But I don't know how to change this part:

```
local_df['enseamble'] = np.select([m1, m2], [1, -1], 0)
m = local_df.drop(local_df.columns.difference(['enseamble']), axis=1)
```

I write in pseudo code what I want:

```
tot = m1 + m2

if m1 > m2
    if(m1 * 100) / tot > 0.7 # simple percentage calculus
      df['enseamble'] = 1

else if m2 > m1
    if(m2 * 100) / tot > 0.7 # simple percentage calculus
      df['enseamble'] = -1   

else: 
   df['enseamble'] = 0
```

Thanks

## Edit 1

This is an example of expected output:

```
 NET_0  NET_1  NET_2  NET_3  NET_4  NET_5  NET_6   
date                                                                                                                                                                                                            
2009-08-02      0     1    1    1    0    1
2009-08-03      1     0    0    0    1    0
2009-08-04      1     1    1    0    0    0


 date    enseamble
 2009-08-02     1 # because 1 is more than 70%
 2009-08-03     -1 # because 0 is more than 70%
 2009-08-04     0 # because 0 and 1 are 50-50
```

Comment: what should be the enseamble column output now after these changes?

Comment: The same: `1` if the 70% in that row is `1`, `-1` if the 70% is `0`, `0` else

Comment: I understand that, just wanted to visually see the output column to cross verify. Meanwhile you can check @yatu's solution if it helps. :)

Comment: Already tested, it seem not working 100% good

Comment: Done :) Can you check now the example on my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could obtain the specified output from the following conditions:

```
thr = 0.7
c1 = (df.eq(1).sum(1)/df.shape[1]).gt(thr)
c2 = (df.eq(0).sum(1)/df.shape[1]).gt(thr)
c2.astype(int).mul(-1).add(c1)
```

**Output**

```
2009-08-02    0
2009-08-03    0
2009-08-04    0
2009-08-05    0
2009-08-06   -1
2009-08-07    1
dtype: int64
```

---

Or using `np.select`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.select([c1,c2], [1,-1], 0), index=df.index, columns=['result'])

              result
2009-08-02       0
2009-08-03       0
2009-08-04       0
2009-08-05       0
2009-08-06      -1
2009-08-07       1
```

Comment: `c2.astype(int).mul(-1) + c1` seems work only for `-1` not for `1`

Comment: Its working fine for me with your example. You can also use np.select. Check update @AsoStrife

Comment: Ok with np.select it seems work. I try other tests and let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with (`m1` , `m2` and `tot` are same as what you have):

```
cond1=(m1>m2)&((m1 * 100/tot).gt(0.7))
cond2=(m2>m1)&((m2 * 100/tot).gt(0.7))
```

---

```
df['enseamble'] =np.select([cond1,cond2],[1,-1],0)
m =df.drop(df.columns.difference(['enseamble']), axis=1)
print(m)
            enseamble
date                 
2009-08-02          1
2009-08-03         -1
2009-08-04          0
```

Comment: Ahh just realized I ws using the df from the other question

Comment: @yatu i guess that is fine though the expected output i think had changed, so asked the  op to provide that. :)

Comment: I'm not shure if is correct, because I always obtain `-1`.
Also if I put 1 as threshold I have to obtain the same results as the old question. And it is not working... I try other tests and let you know

Comment: @AsoStrife i just tried to replicate your pseudocode, though I think yatu's sol should work if this doesnt