# Set column value foreach row with a specific condition with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

this question is very similar to another question I asked a few times ago: [Pandas set value if most columns are equal in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421118/pandas-set-value-if-most-columns-are-equal-in-a-dataframe)

I have this DataFrame:

```
      NET_0  NET_1  NET_2  NET_3  NET_4  NET_5  NET_6
date                                                                                                                                                                                                            
2009-08-02      2      2     2      2      2      0     
2009-08-03      0      0     0      2      2      1     
2009-08-04      1      1     1      0      1      2
```

I need to generate a new column called `ensemble` that follow this specific conditions:

a) Count of 1 are under a specific threshold `count(1) < 20%`(must be always verificated, threshold can change)

b) SET 2 if (a) is verificated and the number of 2 is greater than twice the number of 0 `count(2) > (2 * count(0))`

c) SET 0 if (a) is verificated and the number of 0 is greater than the number of 2 `count(0) >  count(2)`

This should be the results that I want:

```
date    enseamble
2009-08-02     2
2009-08-03     0
2009-08-04     1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with compare all values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), for treshold use `mean` and for count `True`s values use `sum`:

```
#if necessary convert date to index
#df = df.set_index('date')

m1 = df.eq(1).mean(1) < 0.2
m2 = df.eq(2).sum(1) > 2 * df.eq(1).sum(1)
m3 = df.eq(0).sum(1) >  df.eq(2).sum(1)
df['enseamble'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & m3], [2,0], default=1)
print (df)
            NET_0  NET_1  NET_2  NET_3  NET_4  NET_5  enseamble
date                                                           
2009-08-02      2      2      2      2      2      0          2
2009-08-03      0      0      0      2      2      1          0
2009-08-04      1      1      1      0      1      2          1
```